# How to dinamically add columns in exist dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with fixed columns count: `A B C D E MMYY`

Dataframe is created like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(colsValue)
```

Also there is a full list of colums names: `[A,B,C,D,E, MMYY, AGE, COUNTRY]`

How to create additional columns in dataframe and fill them by rest from `full list`.

Initial dataset looks like:

```
A B C D E 
1 2 3 4 5
```

After should looks

```
A B C D E MMYY AGE COUNTRY 
1 2 3 4 5 Null Null Null
```

Base solution below:

```
for dfName, df in dict_of_dfs.items():
    report[dfName] = {}
   
    allcols = dict_of_dfs_columns_names[dfName] + [x for x in allColumnsNames if x not in dict_of_dfs_columns_names[dfName]]
    print(allcols)
    df = df.reindex(allcols, axis=1)
    df.astype({'CCUNM':'int64'})
```

I got this error:

```
IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

On the line:

```
 df.astype({'CCUNM':'int64'})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```py
l = ['A','B','C','D','E', 'MMYY', 'AGE', 'COUNTRY']

df = df.reindex(l, axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E  MMYY  AGE  COUNTRY
0  1  2  3  4  5   NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Comment: What dos it mean, I can apply this for existing frame and fcreate rest of columns? Where `l` is full list?

Comment: @Mandalina Yes, `axis=1` means column, you can also use `axis='columns'` or `columns=l`.

Comment: Use `df.reindex(columns=fulllist)`

Comment: I got this error:

`IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Comment: Could you checkout my question, I have updated corresponding your answer

Comment: @Mandalina If `CCUNM` is the new created column, it will be filled with `np.nan`. `np.nan` couldn't be converted into `int64`.

Comment: If it has before in dataframe I dont need recreate it,

Comment: @Mandalina If you put this line before `reindex`, will it throw error? The error means it contains NaN.

Comment: It does not work for me:

`df = df.reindex(allcols, axis=1)` after I display frame it has no all columns

Comment: @Mandalina Could you give a minimal reproducible example that after `reindex` it doesn't contain all columns?

Comment: What if before I already have this assigment columns:

`df.columns = dict_of_dfs_columns_names[dfName]`

Comment: Lets is move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245051/discussion-between-mandalina-and-ynjxsjmh).

Comment: @Mandalina It will remove original value of `df.columns` and reset to `dict_of_dfs_columns_names[dfName]`.